# Gender-specific ordinal numbering in German

Tags: icu

For Italian, ICU offers ordinal numbering schemes `%spellout-ordinal-masculine` and `%spellout-ordinal-feminine`. But for German, it seems that only the generic `%spellout-ordinal` form is available (this produces "erste, zweite, dritte"). I would have expected masculine and neuter forms as well. Anyone know if there is a particular reason they are absent?

Comment: What is the reason to not expect the explicite faminine form ?

Answer (score 0):

Just found following note about not supported feature, from [Saxon 9.6 Documentatio](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/config-extend/localizing/ICU-numbering-dates/)n

> For German (lang="de"), ICU does not provide case/gender-variable
>   ordinal word numbering (i.e. only "Erste" and not "Erster").

---

Probably the reason is language specific, i.e. for all genders the numbering is constructed like this

- Masculine - der **erste** Mann
- Faminine - die **zweite** Frau
- Neuter - das **dritte** Kind

And the adjective formation with indirect articles is pretty straightforward e.g adding `"r"`, `"s"` for Masculine und Neutral

Comment: haha, just found-out that your are the founder of Saxonica ;)

Comment: Adjectives (including ordinal numbers) are normally inflected according to the following noun (mein drittes Kind), but not after a definite article. Of course there are also genitive and dative endings.

Comment: Yes, gender specific forms with all possible variations (genitive,dative,..) are going result in suffixes like `e, en, er, es, em` which would be too language specific feature for ICU, thats why I guess there is no dedicated scheme for them